# Temporarily attribute migrated, completely un-owned questions to Community

Tags: feature-request, migrated-questions, homepage

When a question is migrated over to another site and *none* of the users who have contributed to it on the old site exist on the destination site, should that post be attributed to Community until it gets edited in order to preserve the normal flow of the main page?

[image]

Becoming:

[image: Showing Community as the last editor]

Comment: Why? What does this add?

Comment: @ChrisF nothing except consistency - certainly not suggesting this is a high priority :L

Comment: @Rory It's not really consistent, though. When you see Community on the front page, it's because it owns the last edit or bumps the post. It doesn't indicate post ownership.

Comment: if "Community-attributed" the question / answer gain upvotes and later some of the users register at target site, how would the reputation work for them? Note it would better be consistent with case when user is already registered at target prior to migration

Answer (score 5):

Actually, the missing attribution serves a purpose: It indicates that a question was migrated from another site (rather than edited by an anonymous user or "randomly poked" by the Community user), and therefore is more likely in need of retagging.