# Strange things happen when questions are migrated

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, migration

Recently, a question from SuperUser was migrated to Arqade. The user that posted the question, however, was unregistered and did not have an Arqade account. As a result, some strange things happened. First, look at the picture. See anything missing?
[image]
Second, when you open the question to look at the user, the user has an image that suggests that he has been assassinated by the moderators. Would it be so hard to make the user an account if they don't already have one when the question is migrated?

---

> **Related**: [How to handle a "new user" migration situation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34225/how-to-handle-a-new-user-migration-situation)

Comment: I'm not sure, but it sounds like this is by design. StackExchange doesn't want to create a new user for anyone unless the user specifically creates it (and as described in the post you link to, once the user does link his account he'll gain control of the migrated question).

Comment: [Another related suggestion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130600/temporarily-attribute-migrated-completely-un-owned-questions-to-community)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not strange, but expected behaviour. Once the author of the question goes to Arqade and creates an account there, if associates it with his other accounts, the whole situation will resolve itself. The user will once again be in full control of the question and will get the associated reputation. Until then, you'll see what you're seeing now.

What you most definitely don't want to do is automatically create accounts for users without their explicit permission.